# extract component from a list of file names in a column to create a new column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with numerous columns and rows.  One column in particular "Filename" has information that I would like to separate and make into a new column "ID"

```
A   Filename                                                                          
1   Sample.2020-03-16_2345_WES01_FF001_089-267/2355245_H445.FASTQs/AA56789_1.clipped.fastq.gz
2   Sample.2020-03-15_2355_WES01_FF001_089-267/2345245_H345.FASTQs/AA52399_1.clipped.fastq.gz
```

My new df2 I would like to create is

```
A  ID
1  AA56789
2  AA52399
```

I do not have a code written to this as I am just begining to understand sub and gsub.  And help would be appreciate, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `basename` with `trimws`

```
df2 <- cbind(df1['A'], ID = trimws(basename(df1$Filename), whitespace = "_.*"))
```

-output

```
df2
  A      ID
1 1 AA56789
2 2 AA52399
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = 1:2, Filename = c("Sample.2020-03-16_2345_WES01_FF001_089-267/2355245_H445.FASTQs/AA56789_1.clipped.fastq.gz", 
"Sample.2020-03-15_2355_WES01_FF001_089-267/2345245_H345.FASTQs/AA52399_1.clipped.fastq.gz"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract the interested value. In base R using `sub` you can do -

```
cbind(df[1], ID = sub('.*/(\\w+)_.*', '\\1', df$Filename))

#  A      ID
#1 1 AA56789
#2 2 AA52399
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse`-solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(ID = str_replace(Filename, '.*/(\\w+)_.*', '\\1'), .keep = "unused")
```

which is basically the same as Ronak Shah's or

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(ID = str_extract(Filename, "(?<=/)(\\w+)(?=_\\d+\\.clipped)"), .keep = "unused")
```

Both return

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      A ID     
  <dbl> <chr>  
1     1 AA56789
2     2 AA52399
```